# Stop on screen keyboard appearing for Android Emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I am using the AVD manager in eclipse.  Is there a setting that I can use to stop the on screen keyboard appearing when an input field has focus?

I tried has hardware keyboard = true, but then the emulator doesn't seem to start at all :-S

Answer (score 16):

[mstoic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54118998/2828100) works, but with one problem: Google voice typing gets enabled with no way to get rid of it.

Not sure if this is available in emulators of all Android versions, but I found this in `Settings` -> `System` -> `Languages & Input` -> `Physical keyboard` (API 29 emulator). It worked for my use case.

[image: Android emulator for API 29]

Comment: Works for me. Also noticed a keyboard icon appearing the navigation bar next to the app switcher button. Clicking that opened a quick setting to turn it off

Answer (score 6):

The emulated device should have a physical keyboard, therefore negating the need for a soft keyboard.

I tried it out now and this configuration combination works for me:

```
hw.keyboard=yes
hw.touchScreen=no
```

The AVD has a physical keyboard, but no touchscreen, therefore only the physical keyboard can be used for text input, and the emulator does not show the soft keyboard.

Comment: You can find more on the conf file here https://stackoverflow.com/a/27137079/6505847

Answer (score 4):

Simply disable the Gboard app on your emulator.

To do that, go to Settings > Apps > Gboard, and then click the "DISABLE" button.

[image]

If Gboard is not visible, make sure you select the three dots in the top right corner and select the "Show system" option.

[image]

In some apps, you may see the Voice input box instead of the keyboard, you can disable that too by disabling the **Google** app in the same way you disabled Gboard.

[image]