# How enable physical keyboard on Emulator in Android Studio? (Used to work)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I'm not sure what changed but the physical keyboard from my computer no longer works for the emulator (running kitkat in Nexus 5, x86). When i look in AVD at the device's advanced settings, there's nothing for a hardware keyboard. Where is this setting?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Find the emulator's configuration in your home directory:

```
//Located in:
~/.android/avd/<The_Device_Name>/config.ini
```

For example, on the Nexus 5 (created by Android Studio), it was:

```
~/.android/avd/Nexus5.avd/config.ini
```

Change the below setting to be:

```
hw.keyboard=yes
```

Comment: Related: [D'pad Is disabled in emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561251/dpad-is-disabled-in-emulator). Modified as `hw.dPad=yes` to test accessibility feature with up, down, left , right arrow keys.

Comment: Can this be set via `adb shell` or `adbmanager` command line?

Comment: Also needed to restart the emulator afterward for the setting to be picked up. Anyone know if there's a way to use the new config without restarting emulator?

Answer (score 158):

In the advanced settings of a virtual device in Android Studio 1.0.2 AVD Manager, there is actually a checkbox that allows to enable keyboard input without editing the `config.ini` by hand.

Tools → Android → AVD Manager → pencil icon (shown in picture) → Show Advanced Settings (scroll to bottom) → Enable Keyboard Input

[image]

Comment: Note, you have to *scroll down to the bottom* of the Advanced Settings. "Enabled keyboard input" is the LAST ITEM. It took me several minutes to realize the advanced settings pane was much larger than it first appeared.

Comment: For me, it's enabled and still I can't type inside SOME `EditText` fields.

Comment: IMPORTANT : Scroll to Bottom :)

Answer (score 61):

Open and Navigate to Tools → Android → AVD Manager → Edit -> pencil icon)

[image]

Click on Show Advanced settings and scroll down and you can see the option 
Enable Keyboard input (example second image) Check that box and Click on Finish.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

**UPDATE:**

Change `hw.keyboard = yes`.

And make the file `config.ini` Read-only:

1.Right-click on the file open its settings.

2.Make every options on the permissions tab into Read-only(refer screenshot)

[image]

Trust me this will work it happens because this file gets rewritten,when we lock it out the bug disappears.

Comment: @electrofant...No way you must have did unknowingly did something else along with it

Answer (score 0):

Quick script to do it automatically. Make sure to rename the emulator name part:

```
sed -i '' "s/hw.keyboard = no/hw.keyboard = yes/" $ANDROID_HOME/avd/[EMULATOR_NAME]/config.ini
```