# React Native - Is there a way to hide the keyboard completely?

Tags: react-native, virtual-keyboard, android-virtual-keyboard

I'm developing an app for a scanning device which does not use the virtual keyboard at all.
So currently, I only show the keyboard when the user want to open it (by tapping the keyboard icon)

[image: Virtual Keyboard opened]

And tab again to turn the virtual keyboard off.

[image: Virtual Keyboard closed]
 .

However, when I type the Input by hard keyboard (from PC / scanning device) or tap the input, the virtual keyboard still showing up and there is no way to prevent that.
I can catch the event and dismiss the virtual keyboard by:

```
onKeyPress={() => {
  Keyboard.dismiss();
}}
```

But it still create an annoying opening - closing virtual keyboard animation. Is there anyway to stop this animation or hide the virtual keyboard completely?

Comment: Have you tested it on a device with the physical keyboard? IIRC the android OS handles this automatically when a physical keyboard is present

Comment: try enabling the hardware keyboard in your emulator. [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136585/how-enable-physical-keyboard-on-emulator-in-android-studio-used-to-work)

Comment: I have not tested with a real device with physical keyboard yet. I will try right away, thank you!

Comment: Oh, I've already enable the hardware keyboard. If i type with the hardware keyboard, the Virtual Keyboard still show up!!!

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known limitation](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14045) of React Native. You can try disabling pointer events as follows but I am not sure that will prevent the physical keyboard from creating events and you will lose text scrolling:

```
    <View pointerEvents="none">
      <Input
        value={String(value)}
        placeholder={placeholder}
      />
    </View>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the virtual keyboard still appear after i set pointerEvents.
Thank you for your suggestion anyway xD

Answer (score 1):

use props of textInput 'showSoftInputOnFocus'
example:

```
<TextInput showSoftInputOnFocus={false} />
```

documentation here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/d88e4701fc46b028861ddcfa3e6ffb141b3ede3d